# How to avoid “bouncing descend” when object walking down slopes?

Tags: javascript, collision-detection, game-physics

I've been working on implementing slope collision by SAT(Separating Axis Theorem). And then I have a trouble. When my object walks down slope, it moves like a bouncing ball:

[image]

The slope has 3 sprites (45°):

[image]

Here is my current code with JavaScript:

```
slopes.forEach((slope) => {
    //Minimum Translation Vector
    let mtv = object.collidesWith(slope);

    if(mtv.overlap !== 0) {
        object.velocityY = 0;
        object.positionY -= mtv.overlap;
    }
});
```

It works good when moving up, but bouncing when down, I have no idea how to keep the object stay on slope when walking down.

Please, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That won't work. You see the bouncing movement because as soon as a collision is detected, the ball starts to move horizontally instead of fall, so it will travel in a quadratic arc until it hits the slope again. You must instead *clip* the velocity vector to the collision surface.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog If the angle of slope is unknown, how to clip the velocity?

Comment: First of all it is not good to work with absolute angles; better to use the *normal* (the unit vector perpendicular to the plane). To clip a velocity vector `v` against normal `n`, use `v - dot(v, n) * n`

Comment: @meowgoesthedog I found an [article](https://www.gamasutra.com/blogs/YoannPignole/20131010/202080/The_hobbyist_coder_1_2D_platformer_controller.php), it uses raycast to handle slope collision. Which one is better, clip a velocity or raycast?

Comment: They handle **completely different steps**; raycast is for *collision detection*, and then clipping is used as *collision response*

Comment: @meowgoesthedog Thank you very much for these detailed answer. Solved my problem!